# Movable Type mt:Entries with interpolated categories extremely slow

Tags: profiling, movabletype

I have a site running on Movable Type 5.2, and I'm trying to simplify some of my templates where it involves filtering entries in the current category based on them also belonging to another category.

This template snippet (built as an index template, where it just prints out the title of the first entry in each category which is also in the Comic category) builds extremely quickly (1-2 secs), although it is a bit kludgy:

```
<mt:Categories>
 <mt:SetVar name="show" value="1">
 <mt:Entries sort_order="ascend" limit="3">
  <mt:IfCategory label="Comic">
  <mt:If var="show" eq="1">
    Hello, <$mt:EntryTitle$>
    <mt:SetVar name="show" value="0">
  </mt:If>
  </mt:IfCategory>
 </mt:Entries>
</mt:Categories>
```

I decided to simplify it using variable interpolation, and it ends up taking 142 seconds to build:

```
<mt:Categories>
 <$mt:CategoryLabel setvar="topCat"$>
 <mt:Entries sort_order="ascend" limit="1" category="$topCat AND Comic">
  Hello, <$mt:EntryTitle$>
 </mt:Entries>
</mt:Categories>
```

It also takes this long to build if I use `<mt:SetVarBlock name="allCats"><$mt:EntryCategory$> AND Comic</mt:SetVarBlock>` and use `category="$allCats"` on the `<mt:Entries>` tag.

Does anyone know what's going on here, and how to make things faster?  I also have some other templates which would theoretically benefit from these code simplifications (in particular, a Category template which I want to restrict further to entries that are only in an additional category) but end up taking far too long to build with them in place.

Is there a good way of profiling MT to find out where the problem is in its code? I'm not afraid of Perl but I also don't know what profiling tools are available for it.

Comment: Have you tried http://perldoc.perl.org/dprofpp.html?

Comment: In your first code block, where is `$topCat` defined?

Comment: What do you want/expect the output to show?

Comment: @CharlieGorichanaz Oops, that was a mistake - edited.

Comment: @DanWolfgang The intent is to have an additional index template which, for each category, displays the first entry that is also in another specific category (in this case, Comic). The other template where this occurs is an additional category template. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @fluffy Your edit confuses me more: the first snippet doesn't constrain by category at all. It seems to me it's functional, but it doesn't do what you want... right?

Comment: Right, sorry, I should take a step back and just make two standalone template fragments rather than trying to edit these things on the fly. But you understand what I'm trying to do, right?

Comment: Also, I figured out a more elegant way of doing the index template using `mt:EntriesHeader` that just happens to work for that one particular template. I still need to be able to further refine a category context with an additional category contraint for the other template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Profiling MT

You could check out this post: http://www.movabletype.org/2008/10/making_it_easier_to_debug_and_test_your_templates.html

I haven't used it with 5.X, so I can't tell you if it still works, but I would be interested to know.

### Template examples

Using my test blog with 15,000 entries and 20 categories, I am not able to get your first code block to work correctly. First of all, I would expect you'd need to test all entries, not just the last 3, to be sure the results will be rigorous. Perhaps a really old entry is the first one sharing both categories.

I modified both your code blocks a bit to get what I think is your desired output of listing the last entry for each category that also shares a given category (in your case, "Comic", but in my test, "Top Story").

On my 5.13 installation, I found there is a difference between `mt:EntryIfCategory` and `mt:IfCategory` despite [the documentation](http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/tags/entryifcategory.html) stating the former is deprecated in favor of the latter.

When I ran this code:

```html
<mt:Categories>
  <mt:Var name="show" value="1">
  <mt:Entries lastn="99999">
  <mt:If var="show" eq="1">
    <mt:IfCategory label="Top Story">
Hello, <$mt:EntryTitle$>
      <mt:Var name="show" value="0">
    </mt:IfCategory>
  </mt:If>
  </mt:Entries>
</mt:Categories>
```

I only got output for one of the `Categories` iterations, the one where the outer category matched the inner category. I am thinking `IfCategory` is testing the outer `Category` loop's category and not that of the inner `Entries` loop. When I changed to `EntryIfCategory`, it worked as expected.

So my final code was this (including a bunch of code I used for timing):

```html
<mt:Section regex_replace="/^[\s]*$/mg","" regex_replace="/\n\n/mg","\n">
<mt:SetVarTemplate name="timingstart">
  <$mt:Date format="%H" setvar="hours"$>
  <$mt:Date format="%M" setvar="minutes"$>
  <$mt:Date format="%S" setvar="seconds"$>
  <$mt:Var name="hours" op="*" value="3600" setvar="hourseconds"$>
  <$mt:Var name="minutes" op="*" value="60" setvar="minuteseconds"$>
  <$mt:Var name="totalseconds" value="$hourseconds"$>
  <$mt:Var name="totalseconds" op="+" value="$minuteseconds" setvar="totalseconds"$>
  <$mt:Var name="totalseconds" op="+" value="$seconds" setvar="totalseconds"$>
  <$mt:Var name="totalseconds" setvar="startseconds"$>
</mt:SetVarTemplate>
<mt:SetVarTemplate name="timingstop">
  <$mt:Date format="%H" setvar="hours"$>
  <$mt:Date format="%M" setvar="minutes"$>
  <$mt:Date format="%S" setvar="seconds"$>
  <$mt:Var name="hours" op="*" value="3600" setvar="hourseconds"$>
  <$mt:Var name="minutes" op="*" value="60" setvar="minuteseconds"$>
  <$mt:Var name="totalseconds" value="$hourseconds"$>
  <$mt:Var name="totalseconds" op="+" value="$minuteseconds" setvar="totalseconds"$>
  <$mt:Var name="totalseconds" op="+" value="$seconds" setvar="totalseconds"$>
  <$mt:Var name="totalseconds" setvar="finishseconds"$>
  <$mt:Var name="finishseconds" op="-" value="$startseconds" setvar="elapsedseconds">
This code block completed in <mt:If name="elapsedseconds" eq="0">less than 1 second<mt:Else name="elapsedseconds" eq="1">1 second<mt:Else><$mt:Var name="elapsedseconds"$> seconds</mt:If>.
</mt:SetVarTemplate>
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
<$mt:Var name="timingstart"$>
<mt:Categories>
  <mt:Var name="show" value="1">
  <mt:Entries lastn="99999">
  <mt:If var="show" eq="1">
    <mt:EntryIfCategory label="Top Story">
Hello, <$mt:EntryTitle$>
      <mt:Var name="show" value="0">
    </mt:EntryIfCategory>
  </mt:If>
  </mt:Entries>
</mt:Categories>
<$mt:Var name="timingstop"$>
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
<$mt:Var name="timingstart"$>
<mt:Categories>
 <mt:SetVarBlock name="cats"><$mt:CategoryLabel$> AND Top Story</mt:SetVarBlock>
 <mt:Entries lastn="1" category="$cats">
Hello, <$mt:EntryTitle$>
 </mt:Entries>
</mt:Categories>
<$mt:Var name="timingstop"$>
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
</mt:Section>
```

And my output matched in both blocks:

> ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   Hello, Hockey rink gets green light
>   Hello, Judge strikes down collective bargaining law
>   Hello, ALRC explores downtown bars
>   Hello, Judge strikes down collective bargaining law
>   Hello, Undocumented students: What in-state tuition meant to 1 UW student
>   Hello, Freezing for a good cause
>   Hello, Dems push Walker on health care plan
>   Hello, Student Council takes up WISPIRG legislation
>   Hello, Possible benefits, drawbacks for voter ID bill on UW campus
>   Hello, Rally stirs up crowd to reclaim Wis.
>   Hello, Major winter storm sweeps through Madison
>   Hello, Photo: Graduation, Class of 2011
>   Hello, Obama to visit Madison Monday
>   Hello, ASM preps to take on final MCSC appeal
>   Hello, Obama to visit Madison Monday
>   Hello, Republican leadership appoints Johnson to 3 major committees
>   Hello, Jamie Thomson wins global award for embryonic research
>   Hello, Task force to recommend new boards
>   Hello, Faculty weigh HR redesign plan
>   Hello, Rally stirs up crowd to reclaim Wis.
>   This code block completed in 18 seconds.
>   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   Hello, Hockey rink gets green light
>   Hello, Judge strikes down collective bargaining law
>   Hello, ALRC explores downtown bars
>   Hello, Judge strikes down collective bargaining law
>   Hello, Undocumented students: What in-state tuition meant to 1 UW student
>   Hello, Freezing for a good cause
>   Hello, Dems push Walker on health care plan
>   Hello, Student Council takes up WISPIRG legislation
>   Hello, Possible benefits, drawbacks for voter ID bill on UW campus
>   Hello, Rally stirs up crowd to reclaim Wis.
>   Hello, Major winter storm sweeps through Madison
>   Hello, Photo: Graduation, Class of 2011
>   Hello, Obama to visit Madison Monday
>   Hello, ASM preps to take on final MCSC appeal
>   Hello, Obama to visit Madison Monday
>   Hello, Republican leadership appoints Johnson to 3 major committees
>   Hello, Jamie Thomson wins global award for embryonic research
>   Hello, Task force to recommend new boards
>   Hello, Faculty weigh HR redesign plan
>   Hello, Rally stirs up crowd to reclaim Wis.
>   This code block completed in 12 seconds.
>   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Note, on this install, the second chunk ran about a third faster than the first one. In order to compare to your 152 second value, which is ten times what it took me with 20 categories and 15,000 entries, I'd need to know more about how many categories and entries you have.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean to include the `$topCat` stuff in the first code block - please consult the newly-edited version. Both versions of the template (as shown now) work, it's just that there's a massive difference in speed (and whitespace differences in the output but that's not a big deal in this case).

Comment: Which is to say that both of them had actually been mis-edited from the then-current and working version. This is the problem with using MT (with its lack of reasonable version control) and trying to figure this stuff out at 2 AM. :)

Comment: Oh, incidentally, `mt-tmpl-test` is included in the MT distribution now.

Comment: So, according to the profile, the two-level filtered version uses pretty straightforward queries. The interpolated version ends up doing a full table scan with an additional SQL query per entry, for a total of around 16,000 queries. Ugh.

Comment: I rewrote my answer after some testing and reading your revised question. I am not sure I've helped at all but hopefully there's something useful in there.

Comment: This is for my webcomic at http://beesbuzz.biz/d/. I have 1041 entries and 19 categories. Of the 1041 entries, 777 of them are in both 'Comic' (as a secondary) and a series category (as primary). There are another two dozen or so entries that are in the 'Recap' category as well as a series category; this is the one I'm trying to do as a category template which is also performing abysmally slowly when I do it "right." Both of these were previously done with filtered-after-the-fact PHP hacks that generated quickly but were cumbersome to maintain.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the timing-related variable templates; those look useful, and that's also a trick I might be able to use to improve some of my other templates' overall quality. I'm trying to make my site's templates not as if they are built from a continuous series of ghastly hacks dating back to Movable Type 3.3 (which they are).

Comment: No problem. I wrote the timing code to produce a search result computation time, but have subsequently found it useful in optimization testing. Also, you might be aware you can abstract the timing code into a module to make it easier to use around your site. Example of how I use it at https://gist.github.com/CNG/5376133

Comment: Your 150 seconds does seem quite high compared to my install, and I doubt it would be so different due to server hardware.. but who knows. I did rework your code a little bit, so maybe I somehow introduced an efficiency...

Comment: I actually posted that as a question on here so maybe others can run across it more easily. Feel free to comment this new question if you find anything better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982765/how-can-i-time-how-long-a-chunk-of-code-takes-to-generate-using-mt-template-lang/15982766#15982766

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28137/discussion-between-fluffy-and-charlie-gorichanaz)